# CryptoPP encrypted file is empty

Tags: c++, file, encryption, aes, crypto++

I'm trying to deal with AES file encryption using c++ libary CryptoPP to code an encryptor for my files:

```
int encrypt_file(std::string file_path, Key& key) {

    std::ifstream in{file_path, std::ios::binary};
    std::ofstream out{file_path, std::ios::binary};


    CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption enc{};
    const byte* keydata = (const byte*)&key.key[0];
    const byte* ivdata = (const byte*)&key.iv[0];
    enc.SetKeyWithIV(keydata, key.key.size(), ivdata);

    CryptoPP::FileSource{ in, true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter{enc, new CryptoPP::FileSink{out}}};

    std::cout << "finished encrypting";
    return 0;
    
}
```

when i execute the code, the encrypted file is empty (0 bytes) but if i try to do the same setting *out* to a different path from *in* it works just fine. I do not want to create a new file which is the encrypted copy of the first one though, i just want to encrypt the first file. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Modifying files in place is not really (usually) a *thing*. Write the new output to a new file, then rename it to replace the original file.

Comment: thank you, isn't there a faster way than this? just overwriting the file instead of creating a new file and then changing extension.

Comment: In some cases, yes. But that's usually when the file has a very strict format and you memory map it and then change and rewrite it. In most cases, just writing a new file and renaming it is the fastest.